# ServiceEntityRepository return specific fields for entity and specific fields for joined entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's imagine I have a `Category` entity and `SubCategory` entity, and I need to get enabled categories with all enabled sub categories. But I need only specific fields, and I'm not care about actual entities, it should be an array.

So what I did is:

```
class CategoryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Category::class);
    }

    public function getEnabledCategories(): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('category')
           // ->select(['category.id', 'category.fullName', 'subCategory.fullName'])
            ->leftJoin(
                'category.subCategoreis',
                'subCategory'
            )->addSelect('subCategory')
            ->where('category.enabled = :categoryEnabled')
            ->andwhere('subCategory.enabled = :categoryEnabled')
            ->setParameter('categoryEnabled', true, Types::BOOLEAN)
            ->orderBy('category.id', 'ASC');

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

so here is a few issues:

- if I have `select` and `addSelect` it's throwing exception like

```
SELECT category.id,': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

- if I commenting out `addSelect` it's returning only categories but without sub categories.
- if I'm removing `select` all is fine, but it's returning all fields which I do not need here.

Is it possible to select only specific fields from main entity and related entities with usage of DQL?

Comment: If you are using DQL, it follows you want to work with your mapped entities. If you don't, just use DBAL (get the connection from the EntityManager).

Comment: well, but with DBAL, I need to think by my self of how to group each row  of result to have sub categories as a nested data for categories, right? that is why I considered it faster with dql

Comment: As you can see, it's not faster, since you are still stuck. Had you built the SQL query with DBAL, you'd be done already. According to the query you show in your question, there is not `group` statement, just a simple `left join`.

Comment: You can lookup the 'partial' keyword in the Doctrine docs.  But it has many negative consequences.  Basically you are venturing into the wonderful world of CQRS (Command and Query Responsibility Segregation).  As tempting as it may be to try and stick with DQL, yivi is right.  Custom SQL queries are the way to go for this sort of stuff.